# Spring data reuse Repository class

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have the following scenario with spring-boot, spring-jpa, spring-amqp:

My application is responsable for replicate data to different databases but with same entities, the database which I have to store/update the data will be decided at runtime based on the upcoming rabbit amqp data.

I know with spring-jpa we can have multiple datasources, and with **@EnableJpaRepositories** we can choose the repository class by specifying the base package like this:

```
First DatabaseConfig

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.repo1", entityManagerFactoryRef = "firstEntityManagerFactory",
transactionManagerRef = "firstTransactionManager")
public class FirstDatabaseConfig
....

package com.example.repo1;

@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {


Second DatabaseConfig

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.repo2", entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondEntityManagerFactory",
transactionManagerRef = "secondTransactionManager")
public class SecondDatabaseConfig
....


package com.example.repo2;

@Repository
public interface MyRepository2 extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
```

This works for me, but I would like to reuse the repository class and not create one repository class for each database I have to persist.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/

`AbstractRoutingDataSource` should allow you do accomplish this while using the same repositories.